# Surface integral is $0?$

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I have a quick question: if $\mathbf{f}:\;\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is *odd*, in the sense that $\mathbf{f}(-\mathbf{v})=-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{v})$ for any $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, and $S$ is a finite surface that is symmetric through the $xy,\,yz$ and $xz$ planes. Does:

$$\int_S \mathbf{f}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}=0?$$

Comment: What do you mean by $f\cdot dS$? Are you integrating a vector field over a surface (getting a vector field as a result) or are you dotting the vector field with the unit normal?

Comment: @user7530 Dotting with the unit normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take for instance $f(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$ and $S$ the unit sphere.

To get the property you want, you will need $f$ *even*: $f(-q) = q.$ Then
$$\int_S f(q)\cdot n(q)\,dS = \int_S f(-q)\cdot n(-q)\,dS = \int_S f(q)\cdot -n(q)\,dS = -\int_S f(q)\cdot n(q)\,dS.$$